# How to call c++ DLL from Chromium based App

Tags: dll, chromium, webassembly

I know there is a way to call c++ DLL from Chromium based App is DLL binding.
I want to know if I can call c++ DLL via the way of webassembly?

Comment: What do you mean by Chromium based app? Extension or native messaging host?

Comment: @Asesh I am not sure the difference, I assume it should be native messaging host. Since my App is a standalone App.